# printed text corrupted in web scrape

Tags: python, html, web, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I have scraped a single greyhound race from the site in the code below and I am trying to append the fields.It works reasonably well,but the resultant text it littered with some odd characters both strings and integers.The outcome should look like this,where the left side is the field name,and the right side the field data......

```
'date''17/01/16',
'datetime''11:34',
'distance''470m',
'fin''1',
'grade''A6',
'greyhound''Cissies Chief',
'prizes''1st \£56, Others \£20  Race Total \£156',
'sp''4/1',
'timeDistance''29.17',
'timeSec''4.44',
'track''Belle Vue',
'trap'5',
```

But the actual outcome looks like this

```
[{'date': u'17/01/16',
  'datetime': u'11:34\xa0|',
  'distance': u'470m\xa0|',
  'fin': u'1',
  'grade': u'A6\xa0|',
  'greyhound': u'Cissies Chief',
  'prizes': u'1st \xa356, Others \xa320  Race Total \xa3156',
  'sp': u'4/1',
  'timeDistance': u'29.17',
  'timeSec': u'4.44',
  'track': u'Belle Vue\xa0|',
  'trap': u'5'},
```

the "grade" field for example A6 is preceeded by a U,and followed by a \xa0,and the "prizes" text is repleced completely by \xa356(should read £56) and so on. There is also a liberal sprinkling of curly brackets }.Below is the code that I use.Could this have something to do with the program not converting the strings.Any help appreciated.

```
from pprint import pprint
from urllib2 import urlopen

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = urlopen('http://www.gbgb.org.uk/resultsRace.aspx?id=1837958')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')

rows = []
for header in soup.find_all("div", class_="resultsBlockHeader"):
    track = header.find("div", class_="track").get_text(strip=True)
    date = header.find("div", class_="date").get_text(strip=True)
    datetime = header.find("div", class_="datetime").get_text(strip=True)
    grade = header.find("div", class_="grade").get_text(strip=True)
    distance = header.find("div", class_="distance").get_text(strip=True)
    prizes = header.find("div", class_="prizes").get_text(strip=True)



    results = header.find_next_sibling("div",       class_="resultsBlock").find_all("ul", class_="line1")
    for result in results:
        fin = result.find("li", class_="fin").get_text(strip=True)
        greyhound = result.find("li",  class_="greyhound").get_text(strip=True)
        trap = result.find("li", class_="trap").get_text(strip=True)
        sp = result.find("li", class_="sp").get_text(strip=True)
        timeSec = result.find("li",  class_="timeSec").get_text(strip=True)
            timeDistance = result.find("li", class_="timeDistance").get_text(strip=True)


        rows.append({

            "track":track,
            "date":date,
            "datetime":datetime,
            "grade":grade,
            "distance":distance,
            "prizes":prizes,
            "fin":fin,
            "greyhound":greyhound,
            "trap":trap,
            "sp":sp,
            "timeSec":timeSec,
            "timeDistance":timeDistance,

                     })
pprint(rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the encoding of the language kind of like utf8 - charset for HTML.

It's picking up a charset you need to find out which one and include it.

I don't know which one bit I hope that helps.

Edit it's Unicode

Comment: hi Jim,many thanks for the reply,I have run your modifications but I am still getting the same results.I think the problem may lie with my attempt to append the data(get it side by side)I have a programs that prints out all the data to screen sequentially(not side by side) and this works OK.any more suggestions much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

First character is a `no-break space` character (\xa0). It is non-printing character such as one of the following: `zero-width non-joiner`, `zero-width joiner`, `zero-width space` and `word divider`.

It is possible to deal with the problem using the `unicodedata` library.

About the second one - it is a pound sign (\xa3). It is part of `latin-1` character set.

Other references:

[Charbase of no-break space](http://www.charbase.com/00a0-unicode-no-break-space)

[Charbase of pound sign](http://www.charbase.com/00a3-unicode-pound-sign)

Web scraping has such problems so be sure your data is clean ad tidy at each step.

You can try using the following code:

```
from pprint import pprint
from urllib2 import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import unicodedata


def unicode_normalize(s):
    return unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', s)

html = urlopen('http://www.gbgb.org.uk/resultsRace.aspx?id=1837958')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

rows = []
for header in soup.find_all("div", class_="resultsBlockHeader"):
    track = header.find("div", class_="track").get_text(strip=True)
    date = header.find("div", class_="date").get_text(strip=True)
    datetime = header.find("div", class_="datetime").get_text(strip=True)
    grade = header.find("div", class_="grade").get_text(strip=True)
    distance = header.find("div", class_="distance").get_text(strip=True)
    prizes = header.find("div", class_="prizes").get_text(strip=True)

    results = header.find_next_sibling("div", class_="resultsBlock").find_all("ul", class_="line1")
    for result in results:
        fin = result.find("li", class_="fin").get_text(strip=True)
        greyhound = result.find("li",  class_="greyhound").get_text(strip=True)
        trap = result.find("li", class_="trap").get_text(strip=True)
        sp = result.find("li", class_="sp").get_text(strip=True)
        timeSec = result.find("li",  class_="timeSec").get_text(strip=True)
        timeDistance = result.find("li", class_="timeDistance").get_text(strip=True)
        rows.append({
            "track": unicode_normalize(track),
            "date": date,
            "datetime": unicode_normalize(datetime),
            "grade": unicode_normalize(grade),
            "distance": unicode_normalize(distance),
            "prizes": unicode_normalize(prizes),
            "fin": fin,
            "greyhound": greyhound,
            "trap": trap,
            "sp": sp,
            "timeSec": timeSec,
            "timeDistance": timeDistance})
pprint(rows)
```